# Couldn't match type ‘IO String’ with ‘[Char]’

Tags: string, file, haskell, io

I am having a project to do for school where I am required to read from file, being given the head of the function I have to implement.

I have the following function already being give which I assume it reads the file that has the name "file_name":

```
getInputTest file_name = do  
    x <- readFile file_name
    return x
```

Next, I have to parse each line of the text, in order to get a vector of Strings, each element of the vector being one line of the file. This is where I am give the head of the function I have to implement:

```
parse :: String -> [Instr]
```

The first argument of this function should be everything that is read from the file(all lines) and the [Instr] should be formed of all the lines from the file, each element of the vector being one line.(the "Instr" should be chosen by me and I tried choosing it "String", but it does not work)

I already tried this:

```
parse file_name = lines (getInputTest file_name)
```

But I keep getting errors such as: "Couldn't match type ‘IO String’ with ‘[Char]’".

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it? Considering that the head of "parse" function should not be modified.

Comment: `getInputTest file_name :: IO String`, but `lines :: String -> [String]` – you can't just write `parse` like that. You mean `parse file_name = fmap lines (getInputTest file_name)`. If you don't understand this, you should read [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters).

Comment: @AJFarmar I replaced my function with this line, but I still get the same error.

Comment: If you add explicit type signatures to your functions, it's easier to catch this kind of error. It will be "obvious" that you can't pass `getInputTest file_name` to `lines`, because you'll have already noted that `getInputTest` returns an `IO String`, not a `String` like `lines` expects.

Comment: @chepner But still, how can I make this work? What code for "parse" should I try? I still haven't figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

`String` is `[Char]`, so the compiler is complaining that it's wrapped in `IO`. Read eg. https://wiki.haskell.org/Introduction_to_IO for an explanation.

To fix it, you need to "lift" your parse function at its call point to operate on `IO String` instead. This would usually require eg. `fmap / <$>`, but working inside `do` notation then it can be sugared-in by writing eg. `return $ parse x`.

Comment: This is what I came up with:parse file_name =
 do
 let x = fmap (lines (getInputTest file_name))
 return x

Comment: @zzz it should be `fmap lines (getInputTest fName)`, and you only need `return` there if you bind `x` with `x <- ...`. If instead you use `let x = ...`, then `x` will have the type `IO String` rather than `String`, and you can simply write `x` in the last line without `return`. However, that means you could also omit the `x` binding completely: just make it `parse fName = fmap lines $ getInputTest fName`, or shorter `parse fName = fmap lines . getInputTest`.

Comment: @leftaroundabout my entire function right now is:
parse :: String -> [String]
parse file_name = fmap lines . getInputTest
And it still does not work

Comment: The type is of course `String -> IO [String]`. If something inside is doing IO, the type _must_ always be an `IO` type.

Comment: @leftaroundabout And if my function is required to have it head like: parse :: String -> [Instr], how am I supposed to define the Instr type?

Comment: You can't. But anyways, probably `parse` should actually _not_ do IO at all, i.e. it should just accept the file _contents_ instead of opening the file itself. Then it also doesn't need an `IO` type. For `Instr`, you should probably design a suitable ADT.

Comment: @leftaroundabout And how can I give the content of the file as a String for the parse function?

Comment: @leftaroundabout And what would this do eaxctly? Sorry, I am very new to Haskell.

Comment: @zzz This isn't the forum for a basic tutorial in how Haskell works. I *strongly* recommend you read a good basic introduction like [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters).

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> getInputTest file_name = do  
>     x <- readFile file_name
>     return x
> ```

This is equivalent to any of the following:

```
getInputTest :: FilePath -> IO String
getInputTest fileName = readFile fileName >>= \x -> return x
getInputTest fileName = readFile fileName >>= return
getInputTest fileName = readFile fileName
getInputTest = readFile
```

> ```
> parse :: String -> [Instr]
> parse file_name = lines (getInputTest file_name)
> ```

Since `getInputTest :: FilePath -> IO String` and `lines :: String -> [String]`, you must, as A Tayler says, *lift* `lines` such that it works in the context of `IO`.

Doing `fmap lines` you get the type `Functor f => f String -> f [String]`, which, when specialising `f` to `IO`, becomes `IO String -> IO [String]`. This matches the output type of `readFile` and so the functions may compose:

```
parse :: FilePath -> IO [String]
parse fileName = fmap lines (getInputTest fileName)
```

I'm not sure what kind of type `Instr` is and if there is further parsing than what `lines` does to turn a `String` line into an `Instr`; if there isn't, perhaps you could combine the two functions into one:

```
type Instr = String

fromFile :: FilePath -> IO [Instr]
fromFile = fmap lines . readFile
```